# Convert blob image to jpg format in oracle or nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, plsql

I have more than 2 million images saved on server folder, they were in .tiff format but their extensions were renamed to .jpg , my database is oracle and images reference are saved as bfile in table, when i try to get that image with nodejs as buffer image on front-end and i convert them to base64 it show some grey image instead of real image, when i place original .jpg file it works fine
how can i get that image in nodejs express api or is there any function that can convert that image to jpg in oracle ?

Comment: You should maybe show some relevant code too...

Comment: File extension has no any influence on the encoding format. It's just a hint for your OS/client which program should be used for decoding. Please provide some sample code and data to reproduce the issue